# Filter by merge commits?

Tags: git

I'd like to get a merge commit's ID if the commit message contains `Task-152`, `Task-352` or `Task-464`. It should sort by merge date (oldest first).

Do I need to use `git log --merges`, and if so, how to filter it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```
git log --merges --grep 'Task-152' --oneline
```

should give you a list of merges mentioning your ticket. If you want it in a machine readable format you can use the format argument to extract just the commit id

```
git log --merges --grep 'Task-152' --format='%h'
```

Comment: Add `%s` into the format string (eg `'%h %s'`). `--oneline` should include the hash and commit message though.

Answer (score 3):

You can combine `--merges` with `--grep`, like this:

```
git log --merges --grep Task-152 --grep Task-352 --grep Task-464
```

This will show all merge commits that contain one of your specified strings. This will by default list newest first, but you can add `--reverse` to have it list oldest first.

Comment: As an alternative, [`git rev-list`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list) supports the same filtering options and it will display the commits in reverse chronological order by default.